# DBCC- InvoiceItem(s) found where PrimaryCmsnPayable does not equal the CmsnPayable on the Primary Item Commission

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I am working on the following DBCC - "InvoiceItem(s) found where PrimaryCmsnPayable does not equal the CmsnPayable on the Primary Item Commission". Unsure of how to fix this. Can someone suggest were the implementation is done in BC's OOTB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where a de-normalized field (PrimaryCmsnPayable) does not equal the value on a child entity (ItemCommission). In my experience this is usually due to a conversion error where the de-normalized field is not properly set. A full solution is much too complex (and unknown given the amount of information you provided) to spell out in this forum. You may have to contact Guidewire support for a datafix Gosu script.

If you have access to the Guidewire Partner portal you can look at article 000031954 to see how to gather information for a solution to a similar DBCC (InvoiceItem(s) found with non-zero Primary Commission denorms and no Primary ItemCommission). This article gives queries to run to gather information and then says to contact Guidewire Support to obtain a Gosu script to fix the DBCC.